# How to move Joomla's configuration.php file above the root folder in a web host?

Tags: php, joomla, content-management-system

I have installed a security solution in my Joomla website,and it's suggest that to put the configuration.php file above the Public_html Folder,how could it be possible?

how to tell the CMS to recognize the new location?

is the solution would be valid in all versions of the Joomla CMS? ,if it's not,so please 
write:

1st:Joomla 2.5 Solution.

2nd:Joomla 3 Solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you would need to modify the **defines.php** file located in the **includes** folder.

Specifically this line:

```
define('JPATH_CONFIGURATION', JPATH_ROOT);
```

And change `JPATH_ROOT` to the correct path.

But the problem with this is that you are modifying a core file so if an update changes the defines.php file it will overwrite your changes and will break your setup. You will need to reedit the file.

Also the `JPATH_CONFIGURATION` constant may be used for other things within the CMS that are not specifically trying to get the configuration.php file so make sure to check that it will not adversely affect other parts of the cms before doing this in production.

Alternatively you can change the **frameworks.php** file (also in the includes folder) directly to change from where the configuration is loaded from

```
ob_start();
require_once JPATH_CONFIGURATION . '/configuration.php';
ob_end_clean();
```

Just change the require_once line to the correct path.

Again since this is a core file it could be changed by an update. But this may also affect other parts if the config file is loaded manually in components or other parts of the cms.

Answer (score 1):

Simply answer is don't do it. This would mean you would have to do what @Patrick has suggest which **is** correct and **will** work, however it means editing a core Joomla file. This is ***not a good idea*** as in your case, if you ever update Joomla, you will have to perform this change every time and it you forget (which is likely), your site will stop working completely.

I would strongly suggest you find a different "security solution" which does not involve having to modify **any** core Joomla files.

If you could define what you mean by "security solution", then maybe an alternative could be provided for you

Comment: Actually RSFirewall suggesting this action.

Answer (score 1):

*I didn't dig for 'since when this has been implemented', But it can be done **without changing the core**.*

Joomla looks for a `defines.php` in the root and if its present, [imports it](https://github.com/joomla/joomla-cms/blob/3.8.8/index.php#L29). **And** then if it finds a constant named `_JDEFINES` defined, it doesn't load the original file, **effectively overriding** it completely.

So, If you wish to override the defines its pretty easy and all you have to do is copy the contents of the `defines.php` file from under the `webroot/includes/` path and paste it inside the one we created in the `webroot`. And you can change the following constant as per your taste.

```
define('JPATH_CONFIGURATION', JPATH_ROOT."/my/supersecret/directory");
```

Now there is **one more thing** left to be done and then we are good to go :)

You have to prepend the following lines to the top of our override file (the `defines.php` in the `webroot`).

```
define('JPATH_BASE', __DIR__);
define('_JDEFINES', 1);
```

This constant conveys to the framework that the defines have been overridden and to use the new file accordingly (*Last time I checked, this flag/constant is checked at around 10 different places all over the framework eg. [here](https://github.com/joomla/joomla-cms/blob/3.8.8/bin/keychain.php#L22), so its important*)

Also I have seen this feature available with Joomla [v2.5.0](https://github.com/joomla/joomla-cms/blob/2.5.2/index.php#L12) and [v3.8.8](https://github.com/joomla/joomla-cms/blob/3.8.8/index.php#L29) as per your requirements in the question.

**Edit:** Remember you have to repeat the same procedure for administrator folder too if you want admin panel to work, and remember that administrator has its own `/includes/defines.php`